# LIghtning datatable returning ID and not name of record

Tags: lightning

I am rendering child records on a lghtning datatable and I want to include the parent name but it keeps returning the parent record Id.

Apex

```
SELECT Name,desc__c, Order__r.Name FROM Order_Line__c
```

js.

```
  { label: 'PO', fieldName: Order__c', type: 'text', editable: false },
```

I have tried changing js to

```
{ label: 'PO', fieldName: 'Order__r.Name ', type: 'text', editable: false },
```

and still no value in column.  Does it matter thats its a auto number field?

P

Comment: One more thing... your 'Order__r.Name ' has an extra space at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the lightning data table shows the current record data, it will not display parent record data. Ex: Order__r.Name

This post explains how to display reference(Parent) fields data in the lightning data table
[Display Parent Fields in the lightning datatable](https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/06/display-reference-parent-fields-data.html)